# Should I replace the window frame while installing replacement windows?

Tags: windows

I will be considering replacing some of my windows in the future. Recently I had my house re-sided and had a chance to see how things were looking "under the surface" for much of the home. There were a few surprises with significant rot in plywood due to leaking around some of the windows, but I think that issue has been resolved.

One question that remains is how to deal with the windows, and what will be involved with their replacement.

**Picture**
[image]

**Questions:**

- Looking at this picture I see rot in both the *sill* and the bottom part of the *frame*, is that correct?
- Would be replacing the frame when the windows get replaced be a good idea? Is it necessary if going from one window type to another (awning vs double hung)?
- What is involved with replacing a window frame? Is the siding effected?

**Desired Replacement Windows:**

- Something that will not rot
- Something that does not require paint
- Double hung. Would consider an awning window again if I could lock it tightly shut. These windows do not have that feature and frequently gap ever-so-slightly open
- Thermally efficient and well sealed (I live in area where heating is more important than cooling).

**Edit:**

This is how the windows look now:
[image]
[image]

Comment: See also: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3685/window-replacement-inserts-or-gut-out?rq=1

Comment: What kind of siding? Can we see a pic of the new siding?

Comment: @shirlockhomes Vinyl siding. As you can see in the picture, the trim(?) around the window was replaced with new wooden trim which was wrapped in aluminum.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the update pics. Looks like the alu wrap is over the sides of the window jams, but not the bottom frame? or is that the actual glass frame in your close up pic? Regardless, the new wrap will have to be removed to remove the window frames. The only other way is to remove sashes and build in new jams to cover window mechanics and create a flat frame to mount replacement windows to. This will require some interior trimming as well, I think... Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: That first window looks pretty rotten by the sill.  But it is possible to do sill repairs without replacing everything.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the windows probably should have been addressed before the new siding went on. Doing the windows before putting on new siding would have given you the option of using new construction vinyl double hung with J-channel build into the frames. It also would make repairing or replacing rotted framing members much easier.

However, since you already have the new siding up (would like to see a pic of the window with the new siding in place) you may have to use replacement type windows. If you have rotted frames, those will have to be replaced and the new replacement windows sized to the opening AFTER the frame is fixed. Of course you can carefully calculate the opening based on what you intend to use to reframe the opening, but that can be risky for an amateur. Keep in mind, replacement windows usually have to be ordered to you exact size and are not returnable if you measure them wrong.  Always a good move to have supplier measure and order the windows for you.  After you install the new replacement windows, you may have to install some new extension jams and exterior trim in order to fit snugly to the new siding. Don't forget to use Ice & Water shield under the finish frame/ over rough opening framing and caulk all areas where water could possibly get in.

Comment: We would have liked to deal with windows at the same time but cost was prohibitive. I will get a picture of how it looks currently.

Comment: Can you reference a picture to describe what you are talking about? I have tried looking at labeled pictures myself, but it seems that some "window" terms are used in different ways in different places. Very confusing.